# MPC5748G Model Based Design Toolbox PIL

Tags: nxp-microcontroller

Trying to run a Processor in the Loop simulation on a general Hello World program using NXP Model Based Design Toolbox on Simulink. The board being used is the NXP MPC5748G. I have received the error:

Invalid payload size (269160464) received during SIL/PIL communication between Simulink and the target application. Check the rtiostream implementation for the target application.

I have taken one of the general Hello World programs from the Example projects in the Model Based Design Toolbox and configured it for Processor in the Loop. From what I understand, I need the regular model, and a second model that outputs to a scope. Both models have a config block. I have attached my current configuration.
[Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOjZ5.png)

There is not much documentation on how to go about using the PIL functionality, so I am not sure if I am headed in the right direction or not. Any help would be appreciated!